# React Router Routing three levels deep, Only works in App.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-router, react-router-dom

I am building a website with the following link structure:

1. `/blog`
2. `/blog/post1`
3. `/preview`

The `/blog` url lists all the blog posts, the `/blog/post1` shows the post in edit view and the preview button in the same edit view links to `/preview` url that shows the preview of the edited version.
My initial idea was to use a `/blog/post1/preview` url but with the use of `<Switch>` it became complicated. It did not work because of the whole `exact` issue where I had to correctly match three urls that start with the same address. So I switched to `/preview`. Now, I can get the first to urls working but the `/preview` renders nothing on the screen. Is it because of where my `<Link>` and `<Route>` are defined in my app. I have following structure:

```
  <Switch>
     <Route path='/blog'>
       <Blog/>
     </Route>
   <Switch>
```

`in the main app.js`

```
     <Route exact path='/blog'>
       //div with some helper views like search bar
     </Route>

     //it is inside map function that renders a card view of many posts, post1 for simplicity
     <Route path='/blog/post1'>
       <PostEditor/>
     </Route>
```

`in the main Post.js component`

```
     <Route path='/preview'>
       //Content
     </Route>
```

`in the main PostEditor.js`
The PostEditor.js has the `Link` and `Route` tags in the same file but not others. Is it a reason that it renders nothing. When I move the `Route` tag from `PostEditor`, to App.js, everything works. Is it a nesting issue or something like that. I tried searching online but did not have much luck with multiple levels of nesting, usually it is two. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
**I am using react-router 5.2.0 and HashRouter as it works better with github**

**Update:**
I have added a sample sandbox to mimic my scenario. Why is the `/preview` link not rendering anything in this case? I would like to know what I am doing wrong in this case, cause I feel there is a knowledge gap about something about react-router that I am missing about creating Links and Routes at different level? Additionally, what would be the best alternative to handle what I am currently doing.

[Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-glitter-jxbc1?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: It's always a good idea to show such problems in a codesandbox or any other online code editors. That way we can better understand how are you using the Route and Switch and Links.

Comment: I have added a sample code link. That might explain the situation better. Why cannot I see anything on the preview page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any route nesting here, but I suspect the issue you are running into is with path specificity and order.

Within the `Switch` you should order your routes to list more specific paths ***before*** less specific paths. Recall that the `Switch` returns and renders the first match is finds, so by trying to match more specific paths first you avoid accidentally matching a less specific path prefix. In other words, "/blog" is a path prefix for the other sub-routes so you want to match it last.

1. `"/blog/:postId/preview"`
2. `"/blog/:postId"`
3. `"/blog"`

Code:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/blog/:postId/preview'>
    //Content
  </Route>
  <Route path='/blog/:postId'>
    <PostEditor/>
  </Route>
  <Route path='/blog'>
    <Blog/>
  </Route>
<Switch>
```

## Edit

> Why is the /preview link not rendering anything in this case? I would
> like to know what I am doing wrong in this case, cause I feel there is
> a knowledge gap about something about react-router that I am missing
> about creating Links and Routes at different level?

The "/preview" link renders nothing because the component rendered on "/blog/post1" (i.e. `Post`) is now no longer being rendered. In other words, the URL is updated to "/preview" and `Post` is unmounted. Since you've no "/preview" route in the root nothing is matched and rendered.

### Solution based on your added codesandbox

You can certainly [nest routes](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting). Here are the changes I suggest to properly nest blog routes.

App.js - Specificity and order matters, place more specific root paths *before* less specific paths.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/blog">
    <Blog />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Blog.js - Render nested routes into another `Switch` component, again paying attention to path specificity and order. Use the [useRouteMatch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook to access the current `path` and `url` props, `path` for nested route matching and `url` for nested links. Notice the route from `Post` for the preview is moved here.

```
const Blog = () => {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div className="blog">
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/:postId/preview`} exact>
          Blog Preview Before Save
          <br />
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/post1`}>
          <Post />
        </Route>
        <Route path={path}>
          Blog Search Bar
          <br />
          <Link to={`${url}/post1`}>Post 1</Link>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Post.js - Again, access the `url` from `useRouteMatch` to construct the nested link to the preview route.

```
const Post = () => {
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div className="post">
      <Link to={`${url}/preview`}>Preview</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-routing-three-levels-deep-only-works-in-app-js-file]

Note: Whether or not you "nest" `Route` components doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things, the overall path structure will be identical. You can just as easily (probably easier in fact) define ***all*** your routes at the root level, and this is common and perfectly acceptable. The trade off may be in maintenance if you want to "nest" a sub-route elsewhere, you'll need to "find-and-replace" all the particular intermediate path segments versus the "nesting solution" you only need to update the path root/prefix. The "nesting solution" is more dynamic in this sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have added a code sandbox that might better explain what I am trying to do?

Comment: Also, would it not be nested routing if there are routes inside the component that is already in the routes tag?

Comment: @Crypton99 It *would* be nested routing if you actually have `Route` components within other `Route` components. I added to my answer regarding using nested routes.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for taking your time to explain in detail. Appreciate it!

Comment: i had the same error and had to resolve this by rearranging the starting with the less specific going deeper for example 
"/blog"    "/blog/:postId"  "/blog/:postId/preview"  in that order and it worked perfect i was doing the opposite when i faced the prolem

Comment: @kelvinnyadzayo Within the `Switch` you should ***always*** render the routes in the inverse order of path specificity. I don't see how doing the opposite could work for you. Maybe you are using a different version?

Comment: @DrewReese  okay in this case i was using link instead of switch so i guess that the case thanks for the headsup your explanation solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

With route /preview we can not identify which blog we are viewing. Pasting a minimum working route configuration bellow

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link, BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

#app.jsx
<Switch>
  <Route path="/blog" exact>
    <Blogs />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/blog/:id" exact>
    <PostEditor />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/blog/:id/preview">
    <Blog />
  </Route>
 </Switch>


const Blogs =  () => {
  return(
    <h1>Blog list</h1>
  )
}

const Blog = () => {
  const {id} = useParams()
  return(
    <h1>Blog {id}</h1>
  )
}

const PostEditor = () => {
  const {id} = useParams()
  return(
    <h1>Edit Blog {id}</h1>
  )
}
```

**Update:**
As I uderstand, You need to display preview right after editing form without a routing switch. For that a button wich trigger show preview element can be used.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { HashLink as Link } from "react-router-hash-link";

const Post = () => {
  const [showPreview, setShowPreview] = useState(false);
  const [editData, setEditData] = useState('Some Post attributes')
  return(<div className="post">
      
    {showPreview ? <Preview editData={editData} /> : null}
    
    <button onClick={() => {setShowPreview(true)}}>Preview</button>
  </div>)
};
Preview = ({editData}) => {
  return(
    <h1>{editData}</h1>
  )
}
export default Post;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question, with a link. Any help is appreciated.